# Highcharts metric prefix

Tags: highcharts

[image: chartimage]

I want the metric prefix to switch to M instead of K once the value is over 1m.

If i use the number formatter, it works but shows the whole number instead of the shortened value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using the formatter to do this by using simple calculations, like this:

```
formatter: function() {
  return this.value >= 1000000 ? (this.value / 1000000) + 'm' : this.value >= 1000 ? (this.value / 1000) + 'k' : this.value; 
}
```

This way you can show values both by the thousands, and by the millions, or with no unit listed all at once.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by modifying the [`lang.numericSymbols`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.numericSymbols) in the setOptions. You can choose any kind of suffix you want. Just put it in the array in the correct position.

Comment: I didn't know that was there, thanks!  However, in my experience, when the chart chooses to switch from one to the other is not ideal, or not consistent - as illustrated in the chart above.